# Should you earn a cleanup badge for rolling back your own edit?

Tags: discussion, badges, rollbacks

I just earned the "Cleanup" badge on Stack Overflow for [rolling back my own edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping/3115#3115).

Should I be able to earn a badge that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, why not?

Badges are there for positive reinforcement, so rolling back a post should always be done with the motive to improve the site's overall content (more up-to-date, more accurate, etc.).

So it really doesn't matter *which* post you improved -- it's the act of improvement that's being rewarded.

Comment: I guess it's saying "This is good behaviour", rather than "You accomplished a difficult task".