# Gained the Editor badge for editing my own question

Tags: discussion, badges, edits

I edited my own question and received an Editor badge for it. I don't think that editing your own question should get you the badge.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61855/166155

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bronze [Editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor) is mostly to encourage learning the basic mechanics of the site, there's no restriction on earning it only via editing others' posts.

The related silver [Strunk and White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) and gold [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badges have more stringent requirements including not counting edits to one's own posts.

The [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) has the definitive descriptions:

> #### Editor
>
> - bronze; awarded once
> - Related to Strunk & White (silver), Copy Editor (gold)
> - Edit any question or answer
>
>   - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
>   - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Source: [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m)
>
> #### Strunk & White
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Copy Editor (gold)
> - Related to Editor (bronze)
> - Perform a total of 80 edits between questions and answers
>
>   - Edits on deleted posts do not count
>   - Edits to your own posts do not count
>   - Edits to CW posts **do** count
>   - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
>   - Tag wiki edits **do** count
>   - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit
> - Sources: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), [Tag wiki badge suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59329/tag-wiki-badge-suggestions), [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m), [waffles's Feb. 2011 announcement of editor badge rule changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260)
>
> #### Copy Editor
>
> - gold; awarded once; same family as Strunk & White (silver)
> - Related to Editor (bronze)
> - Perform a total of 500 edits between questions, answers and tag wikis
>
>   - Edits on deleted posts do not count
>   - Edits to your own posts do not count
>   - Edits to CW posts **do** count
>   - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
>   - Tag wiki edits **do** count
>   - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit
> - Sources: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges), [Tag wiki badge suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59329/tag-wiki-badge-suggestions), [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m), [waffles's Feb. 2011 announcement of editor badge rule changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/copy-editor-with-too-few-revisions/80260#80260)